# How to create an online examination in a small class that ensures certain academic integrity

Tags: exams, online-instruction

I am teaching a Calculus class with around 30 students. The classroom is about 100 m^2.

So far I have been using myopenmath.com to assign homework problems to my students. Now I would like to deliver the Mid-term examination via myopenmath.com.

The set-up in my mind is as follows: the students will bring their own devices into class and access myopenmath.com to get the exam problems. The exam is an open-book exam, but the students are not allowed to receive support from anyone else. I’ll wander around the class and supervise the exam.

**My question**: do we have any kind of technology to support this exam so that it minimises the chance of trying to cheat from the students?

My problem is that I have to run the exam on my own, without any support from the university. Of course, the traditional examination form (written exam) might help to prevent academic misconduct. But I love the advantage of myopenmath.com in providing immediate feedback and creating randomized questions.

Comment: I don't understand the premise of the question. Why in the world would you shoot yourself in the foot by doing an in-person exam digitally? It creates a totally unmanageable situation with a perfect opportunity for cheating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best technology in those circumstances is the "print" feature of MyOpenMath. Could you have each student print out their copy of the exam, take it on paper, and then have access to the solutions immediately after the time runs out?

No internet + randomized questions => probably no cheating

[In the "create print version", you can select "create key" in case you want to have the full solutions available on paper, too.]

Comment: I didn't know this feature. So I would print out many different versions of the assignment on paper and grade them later on by hand? Where can I find "create print version"? I have gone around but could find this on myopenmath.com.

Comment: View your exam questions, and at the top left should be a button for "create print version". Then you can select how many different versions you want to create, whether it has a key provided, whether to include in-between text. I've never done this, but if I had a sit-down exam possible and wanted to use the randomization of MOM, this is what I would try.

Comment: Thks Nick. I have got it.

Comment: Of course, in a controlled environment like an in-person class, I don not know the benefit of having randomized questions. If you're going to end up printing off copies for your students, what do you hope to get from randomization?

[Comment: The MyOpenMath forums have quite a few active users who will be able to answer specific questions about using MOM for exams.]